# Ho to send bulk commands to cisco ASA with ssh

Tags: ssh, cisco, bulk, asa

I don't have a lab ASA version, so I have to be 200% sure before I spoil a firewall.
How can I send 5-10 commands in bulk to cisco ASA with ssh?

I would consider something like this:

ssh admin@my_asa < list_of_commands.txt

Best would be to not to hardcode password in txt file but it is not crucial.

Answer (score 0):

you can save a configuration file and then upload it via SSH to the router .